# request getting denied not able to generate output for python program (DISTANCE MATRIX)

Tags: python, google-maps

I am not able to get my output for distance matrix in Python using google api key. trying to find distance between to destinations.

```
import requests
import json
originPoint =input("Please enter your origin:")
destinationPoint=input("Please enter your destination:")
key='AIzaSyBGaeN96kX3WYj6Q3Oq5umUARRBNI5oJR0'
url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?'
r = requests.get(url + 'origin'+originPoint+'&destination='+destinationPoint+'AIzaSyBGaeN96kX3WYj6Q3Oq5umUARRBNI5oJR0'+key)
res= r.json()
print(res)
```

Output:

```
Please enter your origin:mumbai
Please enter your destination:pune
{'destination_addresses': [], 'error_message': 'You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs. For additional information, please refer to http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account', 'origin_addresses': [], 'rows': [], 'status': 'REQUEST_DENIED'}
```

My request getting denied.

i expect the output of Mumbai to Pune distance between these places.

Comment: Did you mean to use something like `&key=` instead of inserting the key twice into the URL?

Comment: Is that your live key that I can now use too? Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You need to format the request like this:

```
r = requests.get(url + 'origins='+originPoint+'&destinations='+destinationPoint+'&key='+key)
```

But `requests` lets you pass parameters as a dictionary, which is better because it saves you from having to format the parameter string yourself:

```
params = {
    "origins": originPoint,
    "destinations": destinationPoint,
    "key": "replacethiswithyourkeybutprobablydontshareitonstackoverflow"
}
r = requests.get(url, params=params)
```

Comment: Upvoted for including the pythonic way as well as the answer to the original question.